typescript 5.7 compiling not assigned variables
I have ./src/app.ts with code
function one() {
    let result;
    function two() {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("one");
    }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "hello_world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon ./src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  }}

in tsconfig.json
"noEmitOnError": true,

when i run npm run build
i see ./public/app.js
"use strict";
function one() {
    let result;
    function two() {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("one");
    }
}

why code compiled even though result is undefined.
but in my vscode red sviggly  line for result variable

From the docs "Initial value of the variable. It can be any legal expression. Default value is undefined." So the variable is not uninitialized, and thus, there is no error.

hm, why editor showing error then ?

Maybe it's using an older version of TS for linting than you use for your compile. See this fiddle which shows errors if you set the TS version to 5.6 but no error if you set it to 5.7  So appearently something changed in TS with respect to "implicit any" handling.

BTW for such type of questions, you should always post the exact error message you get ...

@derpirscher thanks alot for explanation , yeah my IDE using 5.3

This new behavior is actually the 1st item of the 5.7 release announcement.

Checks for Never-Initialized Variables
For a long time, TypeScript has been able to catch issues when a variable has not yet been
initialized in all prior branches.
let result: number
if (someCondition()) {
    result = doSomeWork();
}
else {
    let temporaryWork = doSomeWork();
    temporaryWork *= 2;
    // forgot to assign to 'result'
}

console.log(result); // error: Variable 'result' is used before being assigned.

Unfortunately, there are some places where this analysis doesn’t work.
For example, if the variable is accessed in a separate function, the
type system doesn’t know when the function will be called, and instead
takes an "optimistic" view that the variable will be initialized.
function foo() {
    let result: number
    if (someCondition()) {
        result = doSomeWork();
    }
    else {
        let temporaryWork = doSomeWork();
        temporaryWork *= 2;
        // forgot to assign to 'result'
    }

    printResult();

    function printResult() {
        console.log(result); // no error here.
    }
}

While TypeScript 5.7 is still lenient on variables that have possibly
been initialized, the type system is able to report errors when
variables have never been initialized at all.
function foo() {
    let result: number
    
    // do work, but forget to assign to 'result'

    function printResult() {
        console.log(result); // error: Variable 'result' is used before being assigned.
    }
}


